# Closed form description of a chaotic system

Tags: chaos-theory, analyticity

What's the simplest (or at least, a simple) chaotic system which can be described in closed form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the simplest one is the [(Bernoulli) shift map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation):

$$ B_a:\quad x \mapsto ax \mod 1, $$

where $x \in [0,1), a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all real systems are chaotic to at least some extent. However only a few have closed form. Some of the simplest ones are:

- [Logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) is a polynomial mapping of degree 2, known for its chaotic behavior arising from very simple non-linear dynamical equations. $$x_{t+1} = r x_t (1-x_t)$$

  - $x$ represents the population at any given time $t$, and $r$ represents the growth rate. In other words, the population level at any given time is a function of the growth rate parameter and the previous time step’s population level. As simple as this equation is, it produces chaos at certain growth rate parameters as can be seen from its [bifurcation diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_diagram).
  - In general, the above equation does not have closed form except for $r = 4$. Below argument is taken from [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226048/614823).
  - If $x_0$ is in $[0,1]$, there exists $y_0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x_0=\sin^2(2\pi y_0)$ (and one can even assume that $y_0$ is in $[0,\frac14]$).
  - If $x_n=\sin^2(2\pi y_n)$ for some $n\geqslant0$ and some $y_n$ then 
    $$
    x_{n+1}=4\sin^2(2\pi y_n)\cos^2(2\pi y_n)=\sin^2(4\pi y_n)=\sin^2(2\pi y_{n+1}),
    $$ 
    for every $y_{n+1}$ such that $y_{n+1}-2y_n$ is in $\frac12\mathbb Z$, for example, $y_{n+1}=2y_n\pmod{1}$.
- [Chua's circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit) is a very simple electronic circuit exhibiting chaotic behavior. It consists of two resistors, an inductor and a non-linear resisting device which is usually constructed from op-amps. One can write down the equations for its working. For example, see p.no. 165 [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=GOPtCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).
- [Double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) includes two pendulums with one attached to other's end. This is a very simple system that exhibits chaotic behavior. You can construct its Lagrangian and work out the conditions for the onset of chaos as is [done here](http://instructor.physics.lsa.umich.edu/adv-labs/Chaotic%20Double%20Pendulum/Pendulum_2012_09_26.pdf).
- A simple mechanical system consisting of a [bouncing ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncing_ball) subject to repeated impacts with a vibrating table gives rise to chaotic behavior (thanks to Joe for suggestion). The dynamics of such a ball is often analyzed using the [Chirikov standard map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_map).

Comment: This is a great answer. Another nice one it might be nice to add is the "Ball bouncing elastically on an oscillating table", whose behavior is governed by the chaotic [Chirikov standard map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_map).

Comment: Thanks, @JoeSchindler. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, the logistic map is one of best examples to study chaos. Regarding differential equations, there should be at least three 1st order autonomous equations to observe chaos.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the easiest which still has a rather "natural" form, is the one whose phase space is the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and whose evolution map is a power function, such as the squaring function:

$$\Phi : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C},\ \Phi(z) := z^2$$

so that the evolution is generated by $\Phi^n(z)$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The chaotic set, or Julia set, is the unit circle. This has the straightforward and elementary closed form

$$\Phi^n(z) = z^{a^n}$$

which also permits extension to $n \in \mathbb{R}$; though in this case the phase space has to be augmented in some fashion for it to be a proper dynamical system: when $z$ is in the Julia set, in effect, the "chaotic" discrete-time effect reveals itself to be the result of sampling at discrete intervals of a circular motion of exponentially increasing speed, leading to profound aliasing.

I do not believe, then, that there are any closed forms for true *continuous*-time chaotic systems, such as the Lorenz system.

Comment: Thanks! With respect to closed forms for the Lorenz system, any thoughts on this?:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0960077907004341